# How to do single scrollbar for two list in common container?

Tags: javascript, html, css

There are two list under each other in container. If we start scrolling without mouse moving, scroll will stop when the first list end achieved. Then if move mouse and scroll again it switch to container and then to the second list.

Is there way in order to do common scrollbar for both lists? Or exclude interruption when list end achieved.

```css
.container {
 width: 150px;
 height: 70px;
 overflow: auto;
}

.list {
 height: 50px;
 overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
    <li>Item 9</li>
    <li>Item 10</li>
    <li>Item 11</li>
    <li>Item 12</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
    <li>Item 9</li>
    <li>Item 10</li>
    <li>Item 11</li>
    <li>Item 12</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the example you've provided, it seems that you can't see both lists at the same time anyway. So is it necessary to have any scrolling on the contained lists, rather than just have the outer scroll bar?

```css
.container {
 width: 150px;
 height: 70px;
 overflow: auto;
}

.list {
  border: 5px groove LightGray;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
    <li>Item 9</li>
    <li>Item 10</li>
    <li>Item 11</li>
    <li>Item 12</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
    <li>Item 9</li>
    <li>Item 10</li>
    <li>Item 11</li>
    <li>Item 12</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the overflow:auto by a single one in 'scroll' using the flex method like this :

```css
.container {
 width: 150px;
 height: 70px;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.list {
 flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
    <li>Item 9</li>
    <li>Item 10</li>
    <li>Item 11</li>
    <li>Item 12</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
    <li>Item 9</li>
    <li>Item 10</li>
    <li>Item 11</li>
    <li>Item 12</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.container {
 width: 150px;
 height: 70px;
 overflow: auto;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.list {
 height: 50px;
 overflow: hide;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
    <li>Item 9</li>
    <li>Item 10</li>
    <li>Item 11</li>
    <li>Item 12</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
    <li>Item 9</li>
    <li>Item 10</li>
    <li>Item 11</li>
    <li>Item 12</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).